# onhashchange and onpopstate outside of the React root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, dom-events

I'm trying to use `onpopstate` and/or `onhashchange` on the same page containing a React app using React Router, but the events are not firing. I'm assuming React or React Router is doing something that I'm unaware of here.

```
<html>
  <script>
    function doSomething() {
      console.log(window.location);
    }

    window.onpopstate = doSomething;
  </script>

  <!-- this is my React root -->
  <div id="root">
  </div>

</html>
```